# DNS - Do I need an A record to redirect entire site with CNAME?

Tags: redirect, dns, record, cname

I am new to DNS, and thought I understood how CNAME works until I read that you also need an A record to go with it.

What I am trying to do is fairly simple - just redirect all requests from *.mysite.mobi to m.mysite.com .

So, in the DNS for mysite.mobi, I was going to enter...

```
*.mysite.mobi.    CNAME    m.mysite.com.
```

...but do I need to specify an A record too, like this?...

```
m.mysite.com.    A    123.456.789.0 (The IP address of m.mysite.com)
```

...but if that's correct, it means I'd need to specify the IP address of m.mysite.com both in the above DNS record (or mysite.mobi) and also in m.mysite.com's DNS record - a duplication which seems a bit unnecessary.

So can anyone help me out with the correct/best way to achieve the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used web forwarding instead.

Answer (score 0):

You only need an **A** record to redirect a site to another one. **CNAME** records are aliases. As far as I know not all registrars support adding a wildcard to the **CNAME** record, so in your case you may or may not have to specify the alias. One that is very commonly used is the prefix *www*.

Answer with an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486089/4782740) to a similar question.