# How to route/redirect *.foo.org → *.foo.biz via DNS records?

Tags: redirect, dns, cname, wildcard-subdomain

I registered my domain **foo.org** and along with it they gave me **foo.biz** for free. I don't really like it, but as I said, they gave it to me for free... And I want to route absolutely every request involving **foo.biz** to **foo.com**, including subdomains.

In the DNS configuration of **foo.org**, I set up **@** and **www**, as well as the wildcard subdomain ***** as **A** records to my host's IP address,

For the DNS configuration of **foo.biz**, I was thinking of using 301 redirects but they don't play well with wildcard subdomains, or at least I have no idea how to achieve the automatic mapping I want, i.e., without having to do it manually for each subdomain and not use without the wildcard.

Since I really want to make **foo.org** the canonical name and have **foo.biz** just as a cheap alias, it makes sense to resort to CNAME records, but how can I do that in order to achieve the mapping???

I'd appreciate your most educated advice!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this by simply using DNS. Sure you can setup a CNAME record for ***.foo.biz** to **foo.org** but that won't make browsers request **foo.org** when a user types **foo.biz** in her browser's address bar. You have to use redirects on the HTTP server level to achieve this.

### Why?

To make myself clear, let's have a look at the DNS setup of stackoverflow.com:

```
~# dig www.stackoverflow.com
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackoverflow.com.         IN     A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.stackoverflow.com.   300    IN     CNAME   stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com.       24     IN     A       192.252.206.16
```

As we can see, stackoverflow.com is the canonical name of www.stackoverflow.com. But still, if I type **www.stackoverflow.com** in my browser's address bar, it will send the following request to 192.252.206.16:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

The interesting bit here is that Chrome may have looked at StackOverflow's DNS configuration and may have seen that **stackoverflow.com** is that server's canonical name, but it still sent **www.stackoverflow.com** in the `Host` header field. This allows administrators to host multiple sites on one physical machine ([name-based virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based)).

However, the server at 192.252.206.16 responds to my request with

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/
Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 11:00:43 GMT
Content-Length: 148

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/">here</a></body>
```

and thus redirects me to stackoverflow.com.

### HTTP Server Configuration

In order to achieve your mapping, you need to add some rewrite rules in your HTTP server configuration. For Apache this could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.biz
    ServerAlias *.foo.biz

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =foo.biz
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.org$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).foo.biz$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.foo.org$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will rewrite **foo.biz/bar** to **foo.org/bar** and **anything.foo.biz/something** to **anything.foo.org/something**. You still need the DNS entries for foo.biz and the site configurations for the foo.org sites, though.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer in quiet protest because I'm on IIS and I'm disillusioned that now I have to bring URL rewriting, which quickly turns into a mess when used with old ASP.NET apps and other environments with their own "pretty"-URL modules...

Comment: @khovanskiiªn maybe this will help: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules  
Sounds like you could (easily) import the above rules into IIS...

Answer (score 0):

Adding an **A** record to redirect site X to site Y should do the trick if all you want is to redirect from **foo.biz** to **foo.org**. If what you want, however, is to redirect all aliases of **foo.biz** to **foo.org**, then it may be or may not be possible depending on your registrar. You could try to do that by adding a wildcard to a **CNAME** record. If your registrar does not allow it, you may have to add a **CNAME** record for each alias. For instance, since a lot of people use the prefix *www* it is very common to add a **CNAME** record to it. Depending on your registrar, it should be something like this:

```
  Type          Name                 Value

   A           foo.biz       (points to) 123.456.789.0

 CNAME          www          (is an alias of) foo.org

 CNAME          etc          (is an alias of) foo.org
```

If the registrar accepts wildcards on **CNAME** records:

```
  Type          Name                 Value

   A           foo.biz       (points to) 123.456.789.0

 CNAME            *          (is an alias of) foo.org
```